# Carto legend colours not showing in embed?

Tags: carto, legend, carto-js, internet-explorer

Carto legends are showing no colours in the bullets after manually adjusting colours in the HTML window -- but only in IE. No issue in other browsers. Has anyone else seen this?

[image: screengrab]

Answer (score 1):

That is a known bug in CARTO in which it doesn't display correctly the legend colors in IE browser. You can find the reported bug in this [issue](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/3068)